# Angular ng-options add selected depending on ajax data

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

How would I force ng-options to use selected value depending on ajax result

this one hold selectable values used to loop

```
$scope.selectOptions = 
    {
        "api": "API",
        "json": "JSON",
        "xml": "XML",
        "csv": "CSV"
    };
```

feed holds returned ajax data and item.feed_type is the saved value which should be compared against $scope.selectOptions

```
<div ng-repeat="item in feed">
 <select ng-model="formInfo.feed_type" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in selectOptions" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using `ngSelected?` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: `formInfo` holds the form objects to be submitted inside bootstrap modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using `ngInit` to set `formInfo.feed_type` value to `item.feed_type`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in feed" ng-init="formInfo.feed_type = item.feed_type">
    <select ng-model="formInfo.feed_type" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in selectOptions" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

Check the test **demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/E1QsrY9XPSZnqXRJqHAJ?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot all of the presented working great, this one I can use in my loop

Answer (score 1):

add this line to controller,

```
$scope.formInfo = {feed_type:"api"};
```

this will select the option with value `api`

here is the [demo Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/YY9Knr7SNG6IoVZmHFWR?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

When your AJAX call returns, simply set your model value to the returned value.

```
$http.<callWhatever>.then(function (res) {
  $scope.formInfo.feed_type = res.theNewSelectedValue;
});
```